# Jssor Cant dim near by slides

Tags: jssor

I'm using the near by slider, and I was wondering how I would go about dimming the nearby the other 2 slides that are shown.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default, one slide will fill the slides container.

But if you set $SlideWidth smaller than 'slides' container width, there is chance to display more slides in slides container.

See following example,

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var options = {
            ...
            $SlideWidth: 600,                                   //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, the default is width of 'slides' container
            $Cols: 2,                                  //Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
            $Align: 100,                                //The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled).
            ...
        };

        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);
    });
</script>

<div id="slider1_container" style="... width: 800px; ...">
    <div u="slides" style="... width: 800px; ...">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Reference: http://www.jssor.com/demos-jquery/nearby-image-partial-visible-slider.source.html